# Останавливается сессия пользователя на Ubuntu Aws

Tags: asp.net-core, systemd

Доброго времени суток.

Есть инстанс Ubuntu на Aws.
На нем крутится api сервис с помощью systemd от пользователя.
Периодически останавливается сессия пользователя и связанных с ним сервисов.

```
Jun 25 15:31:49 systemd-networkd[581]: eth0: Configured
Jun 25 15:31:49 systemd-timesyncd[449]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
Jun 25 15:31:49 systemd-timesyncd[449]: Synchronized to time server 91.189.89.199:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Jun 25 15:37:55 systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
Jun 25 15:37:55 systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Jun 25 15:54:07 snapd[29375]: storehelpers.go:438: cannot refresh snap "amazon-ssm-agent": snap has no updates available
Jun 25 15:54:12 systemd[1]: Reloading.
Jun 25 15:54:12 systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt download activities...
Jun 25 15:54:12 systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for core, revision 9436...
Jun 25 15:54:12 systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for core, revision 9436.
Jun 25 15:54:14 systemd[1]: Started Daily apt download activities.
Jun 25 15:54:14 kernel: [3718687.245500] audit: type=1400 audit(1593100454.191:59): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/snap/core/9436/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=4420 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jun 25 15:54:14 kernel: [3718687.245865] audit: type=1400 audit(1593100454.191:60): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/snap/core/9436/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper" pid=4420 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jun 25 15:54:14 kernel: [3718687.380157] audit: type=1400 audit(1593100454.323:61): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap.core.hook.configure" pid=4466 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jun 25 15:54:14 kernel: [3718687.387060] audit: type=1400 audit(1593100454.331:62): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="snap-update-ns.core" pid=4469 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jun 25 15:54:14 snapd[29375]: daemon.go:542: gracefully waiting for running hooks
Jun 25 15:54:14 snapd[29375]: daemon.go:544: done waiting for running hooks
Jun 25 15:54:14 systemd[1]: snapd.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jun 25 15:54:14 systemd[1]: snapd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.
Jun 25 15:54:14 systemd[1]: Stopped Snappy daemon.
Jun 25 15:54:14 systemd[1]: Starting Snappy daemon...
Jun 25 15:54:15 snapd[4483]: AppArmor status: apparmor is enabled and all features are available
Jun 25 15:54:15 snapd[4483]: AppArmor status: apparmor is enabled and all features are available
Jun 25 15:54:15 snapd[4483]: patch.go:64: Patching system state level 6 to sublevel 1...
Jun 25 15:54:15 snapd[4483]: patch.go:64: Patching system state level 6 to sublevel 2...
Jun 25 15:54:15 snapd[4483]: patch.go:64: Patching system state level 6 to sublevel 3...
Jun 25 15:54:15 snapd[4483]: daemon.go:343: started snapd/2.45.1 (series 16; classic) ubuntu/18.04 (amd64) linux/4.15.0-1065-aws.
Jun 25 15:54:15 snapd[4483]: daemon.go:436: adjusting startup timeout by 40s (pessimistic estimate of 30s plus 5s per snap)
Jun 25 15:54:16 kernel: [3718689.181896] audit: type=1400 audit(1593100456.127:63): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/snap/core/9436/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=4553 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jun 25 15:54:16 kernel: [3718689.182052] audit: type=1400 audit(1593100456.127:64): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/snap/core/9436/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper" pid=4553 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jun 25 15:54:16 kernel: [3718689.212835] audit: type=1400 audit(1593100456.159:65): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap-update-ns.amazon-ssm-agent" pid=4555 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jun 25 15:54:16 kernel: [3718689.222505] audit: type=1400 audit(1593100456.167:66): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap-update-ns.core" pid=4556 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jun 25 15:54:16 kernel: [3718689.300833] audit: type=1400 audit(1593100456.247:67): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap.core.hook.configure" pid=4557 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jun 25 15:54:16 kernel: [3718689.305021] audit: type=1400 audit(1593100456.251:68): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="snap.amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent" pid=4559 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jun 25 15:54:16 systemd[1]: Started Snappy daemon.
Jun 25 15:54:17 systemd[1]: Reloading.
Jun 25 15:54:18 snapd[4483]: storehelpers.go:438: cannot refresh snap "core": snap has no updates available
Jun 25 16:01:48 systemd-networkd[581]: eth0: Configured
Jun 25 16:01:48 systemd-timesyncd[449]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
Jun 25 16:01:48 systemd-timesyncd[449]: Synchronized to time server 91.189.89.199:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Jun 25 16:12:11 systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 1000...
Jun 25 16:12:11 systemd[18795]: Stopped target Default.
Jun 25 16:12:11 systemd[18795]: Stopping API_SERVICE...
Jun 25 16:12:11 systemd[18795]: Stopped API_SERVICE.
Jun 25 16:12:11 systemd[18795]: Stopped target Basic System. 
Jun 25 16:12:11 systemd[18795]: Stopped target Sockets. 
Jun 25 16:12:11 systemd[18795]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache. 
Jun 25 16:12:11 systemd[18795]: Closed REST API socket for snapd user session agent. 
Jun 25 16:12:11 systemd[18795]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted). 
Jun 25 16:12:11 systemd[18795]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation). 
Jun 25 16:12:11 systemd[18795]: Closed GnuPG network certificate management daemon. 
Jun 25 16:12:11 systemd[18795]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers). 
Jun 25 16:12:11 systemd[18795]: Stopped target Timers. 
Jun 25 16:12:11 systemd[18795]: Stopped target Paths. 
Jun 25 16:12:11 systemd[18795]: Reached target Shutdown. 
Jun 25 16:12:11 systemd[18795]: Starting Exit the Session... 
Jun 25 16:12:11 systemd[18795]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 5414 (kill). 
Jun 25 16:12:11 systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 1000. 
Jun 25 16:12:11 systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of API_USER. 
Jun 25 16:17:01 CRON[5416]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly) 
Jun 25 16:31:49 systemd-timesyncd[449]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection. 
Jun 25 16:31:49 systemd-networkd[581]: eth0: Configured 
Jun 25 16:31:49 systemd-timesyncd[449]: Synchronized to time server 91.189.89.199:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
```

После этого сессия пользователя не запускается.
Но если попытаться сделать запрос на api этого сервиса, то запускается и сессия юзера и сервис.

```
Jun 26 11:31:28 systemd-networkd[581]: eth0: Configured 
Jun 26 11:31:28 systemd-timesyncd[449]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection. 
Jun 26 11:31:28 systemd-timesyncd[449]: Synchronized to time server 91.189.89.199:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com). 
Jun 26 11:32:37 systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of API_USER. 
Jun 26 11:32:37 systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 1000... 
Jun 26 11:32:37 systemd[1]: Started Session 1208 of user API_USER. 
Jun 26 11:32:37 systemd[6860]: /home/API_USER/.config/systemd/user/API_SERVICE.service:8: Failed to parse service type, ignoring: Simple
Jun 26 11:32:37 systemd[6860]: Listening on GnuPG network certificate management daemon. 
Jun 26 11:32:37 systemd[6860]: Listening on REST API socket for snapd user session agent. 
Jun 26 11:32:37 systemd[6860]: Reached target Timers. 
Jun 26 11:32:37 systemd[6860]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers). 
Jun 26 11:32:37 systemd[6860]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted). 
Jun 26 11:32:37 systemd[6860]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation). 
Jun 26 11:32:37 systemd[6860]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache. 
Jun 26 11:32:37 systemd[6860]: Reached target Sockets. 
Jun 26 11:32:37 systemd[6860]: Reached target Paths. 
Jun 26 11:32:37 systemd[6860]: Reached target Basic System. 
Jun 26 11:32:37 systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 1000. 
Jun 26 11:32:37 systemd[6860]: Started API_SERVICE. 
Jun 26 11:32:37 systemd[6860]: Reached target Default. 
Jun 26 11:32:37 systemd[6860]: Startup finished in 53ms. 
Jun 26 11:32:38 API_SERVICE[6873]: API_SERVICE_LOG
```

1. По какой причине останавливается сессия пользователя?
2. Как это предотвратить?

UPD:

ASP.NET Core

```
[Unit]
Description={SERVICE_NAME}
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/{SERVICE_WD_PATH}
Type=Simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=5
ExecStart=/home/{SERVICE_PATH}
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier={SERVICE_ID}

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Comment: Лог чего вы запостили? Сервис на чем написан? Если бд? Какой вебсервер? Получить лог сервиса `journalctl -fu service-name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
loginctl enable-linger USER_NAME
```

Ну что ж. Как оказалось сервис работал пока работала сессия пользователя, которая поддерживалась активным ssh подключением. Когда я это соединение обрывал, сессия пользователя закрывалась и соответственно все сервисы от этого юзера. Когда происходил запрос на неработающий сервис, запрос завершался с ошибкой, на что я получал уведомление, после которого я подключался через ssh к серверу, из-за чего сессия юзера поднималась и поднимались связанные с ним сервисы. Поэтому все выглядело так, как описано в вопросе.

Когда я начал сравнивать как я настраивал сервисы на других серверах, где такой проблемы нет, нашел что в данном случае я пропустил выполнение команды указанной выше. После ее выполенения, сессия пользователя не завершается после отключения ssh соединения.

Answer (score 0):

Без содержания сервис файла и типа или языка API годать можно долго.

У вас systemd закрывает процес исходя из этой строчек

```
...
Jun 25 16:12:11 systemd[18795]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 5414 (kill). 
...
Jun 26 11:32:37 systemd[6860]: /home/API_USER/.config/systemd/user/API_SERVICE.service:8: Failed to parse service type, ignoring: Simple 
...
```

Comment: Добавил содержание файла сервиса и на чем он написан. Не совсем понимаю, почему вы процитировали эти 2 строчки лога. 1я строка процитированного лога же в самом конце остановки сессии юзера, а 2я строка вообще при запуске сервиса после успешного запуска сессии